# How to save a Keras model consisting of feature layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feature-selection, tensorflow-serving

I am trying a save a Keras model trained using Sequential and having a feature_layer. feature_layer is created using feature_columns consisting of numerical and categorical features. While saving I get error 
"Layer sequential_2 is not connected, no input to return."

I followed the tutorial provided on tensorfow.org website. https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/feature_columns

I used tensorflow version 1.14 by commenting original code:

```
#try:
  # %tensorflow_version only exists in Colab.
#  %tensorflow_version 2.x
#except Exception:
#  pass
import tensorflow as tf
```

## below code is used to build and train model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              run_eagerly=False)

model.fit(train_ds,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=5)
```

## saving the model for tensorflow serving

```
export_path = 'tmp/1'
with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        export_path,
        inputs={'input': model.input},
        outputs={'output': t for t in model.outputs})
```

I get the error:
AttributeError: Layer sequential_2 is not connected, no input to return.

I get the same error while calling model.input()